# Python: End-User Questions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting pretty efficient at writing python programs where I am asking the user a series of questions, but I'm wondering if I can write programs where I can get the user to ask the computer a series of questions.

For instance, the user could ask me what my name is (computer). If there is code for that; I'd like to know what it is and if they have some beginner lessons on that subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same thing as asking them questions. Instead of posing a question, just provide them a prompt of some sort. Let them say what they want, and then you analyze their input to determine the appropriate way to respond. After you respond, provide them a prompt again to respond in kind.

[Here](http://pythonism.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/a-simple-chatbot-in-python/) is an example.